how to count rows of a correspondent value?
some values in the CODE column share the same value in ZONE column.
when users select a code from a slicer built with CODE column, in a table it should return the total count of the ZONE value of this code.
enter image description here
In this table, when users select 1001, users need to see the count of AA, which is 3. If 1003 is selected, the result should also be 3.
On the Dashboard, CODE is the only slicer for users.
Thank you in advance!

I used MAX to find the corresponding ZONE value.
The result is always either 2 or 1, I don't know how to remove the first level filter - Selected Code.


Try using ALL or REMOVEFILTERS to clear the slicer context.
For example:
Zone Count = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(YourTable),
    FILTER(
      ALL(YourTable),
      YourTable[Zone] IN DISTINCT(YourTable[Zone])
    )
  )

Giving you a result like:


You can try this
   MEASURE =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Table (2)' ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table (2)' ), 'Table (2)'[Zone] = MAX ( 'Table (2)'[Zone] ) )
)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.
